# Is there any way to import the tradingview chart into my ios app?

Tags: swift, xcode, cryptography, stock, tradingview-api

I found an embed code in the "Advanced Real-Time Chart Widget" section in Tradingview. How can I export this to a screen of my application on xcode.

Answer (score 1):

An API would be needed for the values which changes in relative time, for trading view API follow this link- https://uk.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/#operation/getQuotes

It contains all information related to how to import APIs etc

Thanks

Comment: While using an api is the best way I don’t think the linked api is relevant here since reading the overview section states that this api is for broker firms.

Comment: are you using javascript? there is an chart API in javascript

Comment: I am not using anything since I am not OP

Comment: okay then, I think of using another API instead of trading view one, you could also use binance API. It is also a Better option